# Bitmap of size zero saved from Camera App on cancel

Tags: android, android-camera

I was following the android tutorial as follows from this [official link](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)
I wish to save the full Image. The problem is when the user enters the camera app takes a photo but decides to cancel it, android still saves the image with size zero. Any way to avoid this?

The code is as follows

```
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it using the name of the newly created file. When we create name of  file we simply save the path of the file in a String variable say "Current Path"
And add the following code-

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode == 0)
        {
            File file = new File(currentPath);
            boolean delete = file.delete();


               Log.i("delete",String.valueOf(delete));
        }  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong in your code. You should post your code to get the proper assistance.

as far as I understand . You should override  the onbackpressed function. you should close/release camera here. In this case I think the camera would not take and save picture.